# Facebook SDK login sometimes gives email but not always

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6

I am seeing some weird behavior when logging in to FB with the new iOS SDK.  This is running against iOS 6, with no stored FB credentials.

When I successfully login to FB, I am writing the user dictionary (FBGraphUser) to the console.

My initial request is using the "me" graph path, type=user, and fields=id,name,username,email,location,gender.

For some accounts I get the email address returned, which seems to be the email address I just signed into FB with.  But, for many other accounts, I get the requested data with no email.

I do not see any difference in the FB settings or accounts, and the code path is identical for all cases.

Why would FB return the email for some users and not for others??

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... duh.  Somehow, at some point, the two accounts that were giving up their email address had granted permission in their FB App settings for my app to access email.

Hazard of using old code and old test accounts...

Thank you for listening, SO!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, facebook accounts that did not have their email confirmed (on FB) did not return an email.